# What would non-zero character mean if i'm working on the complex field?

Tags: representation-theory, characters

I'm solving the exercises of chapter 14 in  the book Representations and Characters of groups. (Gordon James, Martin Liebeck) Always working with $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

One of them says:

> Suppose that $\chi$ is a non-zero, non trivial character of $G$, and that $\chi(g)$ is a non-negative real number for all $g$ in $G$. Prove that $\chi$ is reducible

At this stage of the book, I think that the natural procedure is to calculate $<\chi,\chi>$ and see that it is $\neq 1$

I know that non-trivial means $\exists g \in G$ such that $\chi(g)\neq 1$, but since $\chi(1_G)\in \mathbb{N}$, I don't know what they want to say with the non-zero condition.

Anyway, I've doing the next:

By definition, $<\chi,\chi>=\displaystyle\dfrac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)\chi(g^{-1})$

I know that there exist a base $\mathcal{B}$ where $[g]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is diagonal, then $\chi(g)$ is sum of $m$th roots of the unity (considering the $order(g)=m$) so $\chi(g^{-1})=\overline{\chi(g)}$

But $\chi(g)$ is a non-negative real number for all $g$ in $G$.

So we obtain 
 $<\chi,\chi>=\displaystyle\dfrac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)^2$

Since $\chi$ is non-trivial, $\exists g \in G$ such that $\chi(g)\neq 1$, but I'm stuck here. Maybe I'm missing something related to the non-zero condition.

Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Consider the inner product with the trivial character.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for your hint.

 $<\chi,\chi_1>=\dfrac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)\chi_1(g)=\dfrac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)$

And since $\chi(1_G)\geq 1$ and $\chi(g)\geq 0\ \forall g \in G$, then we have
$<\chi,\chi_1> >0$.

This means that the trivial character (which is irreducible) is a component of our character $\chi$.

But $\chi$ is not trivial, so it must have something else as component.
In conclusion, $\chi$ is reducible.